# How can I get to know when a user switches from editing any column on one row of ui-grid to any column on another row

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have tried finding any related event in [docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.edit.api:PublicApi#events), but there seems to be no such event. So is there any way I can trigger my code when user switches rows while editing.

My use case is :

On a particular combination of values in 2 cols of a row, I want to make 3rd col mandatory (otherwise its optional).
So whenever user changes any of first 2 cols and the combination matches, I want to show a message to fill 3rd column, but only if user switches to next row (Do not want to show the message in case users already were headed to fill the 3rd col themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using afterCellEdit?

Refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.edit.api:PublicApi

Comment: Yes, I know about this. However, it gets triggered immediately after the edit of any cell

Comment: You can capture the row user is editing by this event and once the user changes row, you show validation message to the user